# php insert foreach just the last element

Tags: php

I have a little problem here, I try to insert all what I get from the selection but it inserts just the last element

```
$dom = new DomDocument;
$dom->load("ResultatTestSuite.xml");

// retrieve elements by tagname
/************************************   ******************************/
$order = $dom->getElementsByTagName('order');
foreach($order as $a )
  echo $a->firstChild->nodeValue . "<br />";
echo "---<br />";

$status = $dom->getElementsByTagName('status');
foreach($status as $b)
  echo $b->firstChild->nodeValue . "<br />";
echo "---<br />";

$message = $dom->getElementsByTagName('message');
foreach($message as $c)
  echo $c->firstChild->nodeValue . "<br />";
echo "---<br />";   

$timeTaken = $dom->getElementsByTagName('timeTaken');
foreach($timeTaken as $d)
  echo $d->firstChild->nodeValue . "<br />";


/************************************   ******************************/
// database configuration

$host = "-----";
$user = "-----";
$passwd = "----";
$bdd = "-----";

$connect = mysql_connect($host,$user,$passwd) or die("erreur de connexion au serveur $host");
mysql_select_db($bdd) or die("erreur de connexion a la base de donnees");


$query2 = "INSERT INTO xml VALUES('$a->textContent','$b->textContent','$c->textContent','$d->textContent')";
$result2 = mysql_query($query2);
```

Comment: 1. Don't use mysql_* functions they are depracated. 2. You don't insert records in loop so how did you expect more than 1 row to be added.

Comment: Probably `$a`, `$b`, `$c`, `$d` are your last iteration's items.

Comment: I'm actually surprised you get something inserted into the table.  I would imagine $a, $b, $c, and $d would be unset after the `foreach()` statement.

Comment: INSERT INTO table_name (column1,column2,column3,...)
VALUES (value1,value2,value3,...);

Answer (score 0):

You just need to wrap required code with `{}`.
In you code only `echo $d->firstChild->nodeValue . "<br />";` is executed as a part of `foreach` statement.

```
/************************************   ******************************/
//info base de données 

$host = "-----";
$user = "-----";
$passwd = "----";
$bdd = "-----";

$connect = mysql_connect($host,$user,$passwd) or die("erreur de connexion au serveur $host");
mysql_select_db($bdd) or die("erreur de connexion a la base de donnees");

$dom = new DomDocument;
$dom->load("ResultatTestSuite.xml");

//recuperation des elements par rapport au nom de la balise
/************************************   ******************************/
$order = $dom->getElementsByTagName('order');
foreach($order as $a ) {
   echo $a->firstChild->nodeValue . "<br />";
   echo "---<br />";

   $status = $dom->getElementsByTagName('status');
   foreach($status as $b) { 
      echo $b->firstChild->nodeValue . "<br />";
      echo "---<br />";

      $message = $dom->getElementsByTagName('message');
      foreach($message as $c) {
         echo $c->firstChild->nodeValue . "<br />";
         echo "---<br />";   

         $timeTaken = $dom->getElementsByTagName('timeTaken');
         foreach($timeTaken as $d) {
            echo $d->firstChild->nodeValue . "<br />";

            $query2 = "INSERT INTO xml VALUES('" . mysql_real_escape_string($a->textContent) . "','" . mysql_real_escape_string($b->textContent) ."','" . mysql_real_escape_string($c->textContent) . "','" . mysql_real_escape_string($d->textContent) . "')";
            $result2 = mysql_query($query2);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

**Edit:**

Please note that your code may fail if you have `'` in some of values you are trying to insert. That symbol must be escaped. You can user [mysql_real_escape_string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) function (link in my code above). It will escape symbols that may break your query AND will prevent sql injection. But take a note at warning on linked page. mysql_* functions are deprecated.

```
$results = $dom->getElementsByTagName('result');
foreach($results as $res) {
    $order = $res->getElementsByTagName('order');
    foreach($order as $a ) {
       echo $a->firstChild->nodeValue . "<br />";
       echo "---<br />";

       $status = $res->getElementsByTagName('status');
       foreach($status as $b) { 
          echo $b->firstChild->nodeValue . "<br />";
          echo "---<br />";

          $message = $res->getElementsByTagName('message');
          foreach($message as $c) {
             echo $c->firstChild->nodeValue . "<br />";
             echo "---<br />";   

             $timeTaken = $res->getElementsByTagName('timeTaken');
             foreach($timeTaken as $d) {
                echo $d->firstChild->nodeValue . "<br />";

                $query2 = "INSERT INTO xml VALUES('" . mysql_real_escape_string($a->textContent) . "','" . mysql_real_escape_string($b->textContent) ."','" . mysql_real_escape_string($c->textContent) . "','" . mysql_real_escape_string($d->textContent) . "')";
                $result2 = mysql_query($query2);
             }
          }
       }
    }
}
```

Above foreach loop should work much better, if I understand structure of XML correctly. You just need to find all result elements and then: order, status etc elements inside separate element.

Comment: Have you tried to run code from my answer? Check brackets carefully. This code must insert all values. Of course, if there are no other problems. For instance, there may be `'` in values you are trying to insert. In that case query will fail.

Comment: that insert just the first element 7 times

Comment: First element of what? $a, $b, $c or $d?

Comment: Also, what is the structure of `ResultatTestSuite.xml`? It looks like you are taking elements from it in wrong way.

Comment: no, im sur of what i get from the ResultatTestSuite.xml; that very wierd

Comment: Well... what you are doing there really looks strange and if you would show a structure  of your xml document it could help to understand what you are doing and how your code will behave

Comment: <result>
<message>
Step 4 [Http Test Step 4 [/Data-Services-Products/View-Download/Argo-floats-description-by-WMO-number/(url)/float%3Fdetail%3Dfalse%26ptfCode%3D1900617%26active%3Dtrue%26ocean%3DA%26xml%3Dtrue%26lang%3Den]] OK: took 1915 ms
</message>
<name>
Http Test Step 4 [/Data-Services-Products/View-Download/Argo-floats-description-by-WMO-number/(url)/float%3Fdetail%3Dfalse%26ptfCode%3D1900617%26active%3Dtrue%26ocean%3DA%26xml%3Dtrue%26lang%3Den]
</name>
<order>5</order>
<started>11:10:32.030</started>
<status>OK</status>
<timeTaken>1915</timeTaken>
</result>

Comment: 2
3
4
5
2
3
4
5
6
7
---
OK
OK
OK
OK
OK
OK
OK
OK
OK
OK
---
Step 1  took 4559 ms
Step 2  OK: took 2176 ms
Step 3  OK: took 1885 ms
Step 4 OK: took 1915 ms
Step OK: took 42 ms
Step 2  OK: took 2499 ms
Step 3  OK: took 24 ms
Step 4  OK
Step 5 [Groovy Script] OK:
Step 6 [dateJour] OK

Comment: i dont know if it can cause aprobleme or not but, i have 10 elements in $order and $message and 12 in $status

Answer (score 0):

Keep the Insertion Statement in foreach loop where your echoing the data because you kept that at end so last record only got inserted

Comment: for $a it inserts the good ones , for the oders it inserts just the first element of the $b, $c and $d